# Satellite data pre-processing for Keras CNNs

Tags: keras, computer-vision, tensor, gis

I’m looking at satellite data and want to do object detection using CNNs in Keras. I’m currently pre-processing the data (turning them into tensors) that I’ve obtained which include the original satellite images (circa 4,500 images with 4 channels plus shapefiles delineating the area for those objets).

I am preprocessing the data to turn my images into tensors for input into Keras and I was wondering what I should do with those shapefiles - for me, they add value to the training dataset as they highlight the specific area to look at on the image but at the same time, they’re separate files (either .png or a json with the polygon shape coordinates) and I’m not sure how to handle them.

Comment: If you want to know how to read specific file formats in Keras, the question is [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and it could be closed soon. It could become on-topic, in my opinion, if you removed references to Keras and the request on how to handle the file formats. Instead you could focus on how to use information about the bounding box of an object, to perform object detection. In that case an answer would be possible, and it could for example refer you to region-based CNNs.

Comment: ps note that I have nothing against Keras - I love it and I highly recommend it as a matter of fact. But asking how to read .png or .json files in a Keras model is not a question suited for this site, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that is a trade-off between speed and accuracy (as often in Machine Learning).

I would try feeding them in as well into the Neural Network, but if the computation takes to long I would leave them out.

Also you could just try it once and see if it boosts your performance (and if so, is it worth the time?).

Comment: I understand the trade-offs inherent with machine learning. My question is more about how to handle those shapefiles in practice if I were to bring them in my analysis: 1. add the .png as an extra channel to my images pre-processing? 2. append selected features of my json to my tensor? What libraries / commands could make my job easier (Mapbox Rasterio maybe?)

Comment: I like option 1) add them as another channel (like a 0/1 channel, with 0 being "don't pay attention to this area" and 1 being "do pay attention").  If you have trouble getting the shapes to line up, you could use the shapefiles as a separate input to its own CNN, and then merge the 2 CNNS (and maybe feed them into a 3rd CNN prior to the output layer?)

Comment: Exactly - the idea is to bring in this extra channel as a mask. An alpha channel in some way. I'm checking the GDAL library (http://www.gdal.org/) to see if it would help me do this.

Comment: The zero-one-solution seems very good  (very efficient, if it is possible to extract the data easily)